# How do I use the DCount function so it does not count fields with "Null" values in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this basic VBA script for conditional formatting. It checks for duplicate values. But this function also retruns True for the empty cells. How do I adjust this formula so it only counts the values that are Not Null?

Is it possible to use the Dlookup function instead to compare if my newly entered Number in `me.txt_Number_1` already exists in field `[Number_1]`?

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    
If Nz(DCount("*", "[qry_DataEntry]", "[Number_1] = '" & Me.txt_Number_1 & "'"), 0) = 1 Then

           Me.txt_Duplicate.Visible = False
       Else
           Me.txt_Duplicate.Visible = True

       End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to count values that are not null, use;

```
DCount("[Number_1]", "[qry_DataEntry]", "[Number_1] <> Null")
```

to check the latest entered number, use;

```
DLookup("[Number_1]", "[qry_DataEntry]", "[Number_1] = " & Me.txt_Number_1)
```

is Number_1 numeric?  numeric fields dont need to be surrounded with quotes when setting search criteria per this example.

Comment: Scott, you cannot compare with _Null_ (use `Is Null` in SQL or `IsNull()` in VBA.

Comment: i wasnt giving an sql answer, i was simply supplying working examples of DCount and DLookup (which is what i thought was being asked for).  from there they can do whatever they like with the result.

Comment: I know, but the syntax used in `DCount` will not work as intended.

Comment: ...ah, i failed to check the results i was getting.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try an IsNull() into the query?  Substitute for a field or use multiple with parenthesis.  Something like this:

```
With Me
    If DCount("*", "qry_DataEntry", "Number_1 = '" & .txt_Number_1 & "' AND NOT IsNull(Number_1)") Then
        .txt_Duplicate.Visible = False
    Else
        .txt_Duplicate.Visible = True           
    End If
End With
```